# How to SSH into a linux machine through an attached cellular modem

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh

I have a linux box that I need to shell into. This unit is connected to the internet through a Sierra Wireless cell modem using wwan0. How can I get access to it?

My first thought is to open port 22 but there is no router to open the port just the cell modem. From everything I am reading you can not open a port in the modem.

Comment: In many cases there is no router you can adjust here, and cell carriers tend to not allow any inbound connections what so ever. I would suggest contacting your vendor's tech support.

Comment: Have you actually tried connecting to port 22 from another host?  How do you know it won't work?

Comment: You probably just need to make sure the port is open with the local firewall.  I bet the modem leaves you WIDE OPEN.  As @Stabledog suggests.. have you tried it?

Comment: I just checked both the IPs in the route table and the port is closed. To be clear I am using AT&T so these IPs are AT&T I can not do much with them.

Comment: You shouldn’t have to open a port to make an outgoing connection to a device.  However, cellular connections, often block both outgoing and incoming traffic on common high traffic ports.  If AT&T has closed these ports there isn’t anything you can do about that

Comment: What model modem? How is it connecting to your Linux box? Is bandwidth very expensive? (If not, your Linux box up as a VPN client to a service that offers a static IP or your network, then SSH in over that)

Comment: I am using a computer with MC7455 LTE. I have tried port 22 and it is closed :(

Answer (score 0):

Was able to use reverse ssh tunneling to structure an open port.

Comment: Please describe the procedure in enough detail that somebody else can do it.